# Larevel HTTP client error 403 on production

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle, http-status-code-403

I'm working on a project that calls an e-commerce website to get some information and does analysis on them.

I wrote the following code to get the information:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class TheController extends Controller {

public function getProductAndCompetitors() {

     public function getInformation() {
          $url = 'https://www.noon.com/_svc/catalog/api/v3/search?sku=N29905443A';
          $response = HTTP::get($url);
          dd($response);
     }
}
```

**The problem:**

the code is working on localhost but returning 403 error when I deployed it to a server.

**Additional information:**

- the external website is based in KSA (no idea where the server is)
- when I copy and paste the url in the browser it returns 200
- the code is working on a shared hosting server in US
- the code is working on localhost in KSA
- the code is not working on VPS server is Frankfort

I tried to use GuzzleHttp\Client instead and add some headers but this didn't work as well

Comment: maybe issue regarding they might not like request being send from server as curl, they allow it on localhost but they sometimes block it on requests from a server try useragent

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to low reputation, but I need to see the logs. Check your server and let me know what it says.

This could range from a variety of reasons, and I have encountered to be common the issue of the "missing key" (`php artisan key:generate`)

Comment: no it's not an APP_KEY problem for sure. I can visit my website and login to my account. also there is no logs for the problem since it's not throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

maybe issue regarding they might not like request being send from server as curl, they allow it on localhost but they sometimes block it on requests from a server.

```php
try{
    $url = 'https://www.noon.com/_svc/catalog/api/v3/search?sku=N29905443A';
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
          'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'   
      ])->get($url);
    dd($response->body());

   }  catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException $e){
      // Log your errors
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the response as html saying that I don't have the permission to access.
same ^^

Comment: Then I guess it disallows by checking Ip of server, it might be allowing ip of local. contact the company on whose guzzle you are doing